Time Series Predicting Specific Period of Time
I have been trying the ML.NET framework to forecast some data around me.
From what I discovered, we can use Time Series for forecasting a series of values prediction in the future, adjacent to the last input data date/time.
Is it possible to run a forecast for a previous period of time (in the past) against the same trained data model?
I went thru the prediction.Predict() documentation, and I cannot find anywhere to provide time as parameter.
Where and how is the best case to do forecasting for a specific period of time?
